# 〜と whenever's second clause must follow first clause

Tags: particle-と

I'm a bit confused as to why the following sentence is wrong.

> 私はその人と話すと喫茶店{きっさてん}に行きます。

The book says

> The event described by the second clause must follow the event described in the first half of the sentence.

But doesn't `きっさてんにいきます` happen because of `その人と話す`?

Here are a couple of other samples sentences from the same sub section to provide more context.

> - 夜になると町が静かになります。
> - 秋になると木が赤くなります。
> - わたしはこどものとき、ふゆになるとかぜをひきました。

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you said

> 私はその人と話すため、喫茶店に行きます。

with the meaning "[in order] to talk to that person, I [will] go to a cafe."

then that could work.

But I'm not following

> 私はその人と話すと喫茶店に行きます。

= "I to talk with that person **and** go to the cafe." ?

or "**when** I talk to the person, then I go to the cafe" ?

Or at least that's what **と** would do for me meaningwise.

If the と you're using is the one for conditionals, then it takes on a meaning of "when" as in when the condition preceded by と is met, then the second half follows.

> 私はその人と話すと、喫茶店に入る許可をもらいました。

= if/when I talk to that person, I receive permission to enter the cafe. (apparently it's a pretty exclusive joint!)

I think that's what the book is trying to tell you. Or rather と has a 前後関係 not matched by the other conditionals possible in Japanese such that the left precedes the right.

AとB　means whenever in the sense of "Whenever A has occurred, then B always occurs after  that"  or "After A has happened, then B happens." Thus, it's the best way to translate "if, then" sentences in logic. It does not refer to concurrent events of A and B, because it temporally distinguishes the events.

Comment: Hey @virmaior thanks for the reply. I've added more context, essentially the chapter's about `whenever`. So what I got from the sentence was whenever I talk to that person we go to a cafe and I'm not quite sure why that is wrong or is my translation just wrong.

Comment: AとB　always means after A, then B.   If you want to say "whenever I talk to this person, we go to the cafe" then `この人と話す(とき/場合)、喫茶店に行きます`

Answer (score 2):

Think of this 〜と pattern as "B is a natural/obvious result of A happening".  Here's a classic textbook example:

> - エレベーターのボタンを押すと、ドアが開きました。　→　"When I pressed the elevator('s) button, the door opened."  or "I pressed the button, and the door opened."

So when your book says "The event described by the second clause ***must follow*** the event described in the first half of the sentence", this is not incorrect, but it's a bit misleading.  It means to logically follow as a result, not just follow temporally.

This is why the first sentence is incorrect; going to a coffee shop is not an obvious/natural result of talking to someone.  If it were, everyone would like permanently be in, or going to, coffee shops.

So if you just remember the "natural/obvious result" thing, it should make this pattern easier to remember and use.  Because of this, the B can rarely (never?) be something subjective like a decision, since an action based on your own discretion is not likely to be obvious to everyone.